# Managing a database with GIS: How can I fill a database with attributes?

Tags: qgis

I have a database in Google Earth from plots of land all over a city, I have information in different folders of the server. I want to analyze its financial feasibility and connect it with the server if possible. So, I want to extract (or input information in the GIS). I need to retrieve key attributes that for the analysis of every plot that is (land use, slope, average housing price in 3.5 and 4. 5 km radius, and other conditions). I was thinking of filling the necessary information as an attribute in a shapefile using QGIS the extracted to an Excel spreadsheet. However, I am not sure how to do so.

How would you build such a database?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour].  None of the things you have mentioned are what would be considered a database. I think you want the term "dataset". Databases and database design are large topics, much larger than what is considered appropriate for our "Focused question/Best answer" model. There's also many, many options, which would tend to make this question *opinion-based*.

Answer (score 2):

GIS and Database management are both technical fields which people spend years studying. It sounds like you have a complicated assignment for which you lack the necessary training, knowledge and experience.

- If you need to complete this task quickly, consider hiring a consultant with the necessary technical skills to help you set this up.
- If you prefer to do it yourself, plan to spend a substantial amount of time learning. Start by finding and reading a beginners guide to database management.

Keep in mind that a poorly set up database will cost you time and money down the line. It's worth taking the time to set it up right.